# Tumblr API 2: Where is the "OAUTH_TOKEN" and "OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET"

Tags: python, api, oauth, tumblr

I want to use Tumblr API 2, http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

I have already registered an Application here: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps

But I only get the "OAuth Consumer Key" and "Secret Key". Where is the  "OAUTH_TOKEN" and "OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET"?

One program https://gist.github.com/1242662 needs these parameters:

```
class TumblrAPIv2:
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret):
        self.consumer = oauth2.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        self.token = oauth2.Token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
        self.url = "http://api.tumblr.com"
```

Answer (score 31):

Probably this is old thread and you might have figured out how to work with it, Although I am trying to post the entire process for some newbies here, As it took a while for me to understand the entire process and work flow.

I have worked a lot with OAuth v2 and Tumblr API.

1. First and foremost we need to get registered to tumblr and once its done you get CONSUMER KEY and SECRET. These are the initial set of keys for further process.
2. After you have registerd and trying to communicate to the provider, we need request for REQUEST TOKEN and SECRET. This is one time access and it has nonce time attached to them. You can get that here (https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info).
3. Once you have REQUEST TOKEN AND SECRET. At this point you have registered your application and granted requested access to provider. Now you need to authorize yourself with the provider using /authorize url. At this point you get back OAUTH TOKEN and OAUTH VERFIER.
4. Once you have above tokens last step of this process is to fetch ACCESS TOKEN ANS TOKEN SECRET by apssing OAUTH TOKEN and CONSUMER KEY using /access/ url. After this step is succesfull you have ACCESS TOKEN.
5. Now store your CONSUMER KEY AND SECRET from first step and ACCESS TOKEN AND TOKEN SECRET from 4th step somewhere safe and use these keys in future for any communication to the provider.

NOTE: 1. Its generally assumed that access token expire but in reality they don't expire. They will expire only if user revokes the access. 
2. After you have your token you can change your login credentials of Tumblr any number of times, this WILL NOT EFFECT the keys fetched.

I hope this is helpful for someone looking for the process and myths and questions regarding the process.

Comment: what is the OAuth Verifier for?

Comment: Hello Shilpa, I am exactly following your steps, however i have an issue. when i recieve oath_verifier from the call back url and i request access token, i recieve an error "oath signature does not match expected value". I googled it and saw that it may be because of HTTPS, so i changed the url to HTTPS but it doesnt work

Comment: @HassanAkhtar The Twitter API is similar to the Tumblr API, have a look at this doc and how they go about doing things, it will help you with Tumblr because the method of acquiring the tokens are very similar: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-oauth-1/

For devs wishing to use PHP then Tumblr has a PHP client here: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php

Answer (score 15):

The steps given by @Shilpa are now [automated here](https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info). Go to that page and input your `consumer_key` & `consummer_secret`. You'll get back `oauth_token` & `oauth_token_secret`.

Answer (score 2):

Those OAuth Token and Token Secret come from the registration process. This code assumes that the user is already registered and has authorized your application with Tumblr. You can find code that walks you through the registration/authorization process on [Google Code](http://oauth.net/code/).

Comment: Thanks. What is the "CALLBACK_URL" supposed to be?

Comment: CALLBACK_URL is for Tumblr to call your application back during user registration/authorization.

Answer (score 2):

Please look in to this URL and please select appropriate API Language ( Java or Python or other )

https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info

It'll shows your 
consumer_key/consumer_secret/oauth_token/oauth_token_secret

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tumblr API Docs suck -- they don't have the OAuth explained and force you to use their libraries.

---

Having `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` you get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` from `https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token`

Then if you want to make calls authorized by a user you lead him to `https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=...` where he gets `oauth_verifier` for you -- you now use it to get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_verifier` to use them instead of those `oauth_` tokens that you got in the beginning.